# How do I get the exact scroll position in an Listbox?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I would like to be able to load more data into a listbox when I reach the begining or the end of the listbox.

My listbox shows items that are time related therefor when I reach the top and pull down I would like to see some text like "Scroll down more to retrieve more items" and if you do so it then triggers a data download for items that occur earlier.

Same thing for the bottom item if you scoll down far enough (beneath the last item it triggers a data download for items later than listed).

I'm not after a seamless listbox I want the data download to trigger only if I scroll upp or down far enough and release.
I hope this description makes sense.

Basically what I need to know is the exact scroll position in the Listbox and so that I can detemine when the list has been dragged and released far down or up.
For those who have IPhone the effect I'm after is used in the Facebook app.

Cheers

/Jimmy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for two separate things. First, you need to change the default layout of the ListBox to have an ending control. A pretty decent implementation was [presented here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/cdf2716d-0ceb-4c03-9e26-cbe9f53328d8) - you are basically inserting an extra control after the `ItemPresenter` in the default template.

Looking for dynamic loading, [here is an implementation](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

To get the exact scroll position you need to get at the ListBox's ScrollViewer.  I use this for Pivots (to return the the previous scrolling position after tombstoning) - I assume it will work for ListBoxes too..

```
var scrollViewer = FindScrollViewer(listBox);
var offset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;

static ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        var elt = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (elt is ScrollViewer) return (ScrollViewer)elt;
        var result = FindScrollViewer(elt);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of your samples helped to get my project done.
However I can only set one answer as the solution =/